# How to get to pylint part of settings.json in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I wanted to set up Python linting and Django compatibility in Visual Studio Code (VSC). So I installed the Python and Djaneiro extensions. And pylint and pylint-django pip packages in my Django venv. I then went to look for the settings for the linting extensions via File->Preferences->Settings. But I couldn't see how to reach the section on pylint for the json settings file, it seems to have moved/changed recently in VSC. I just wanted to add:

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins",
    "pylint_django"
]
```

I'm guessing you can edit the file some other way (although I don't know where it is on the disk) rather than jumping to the section via the VSC interface. VSC version is 1.51.1, on Windows 10.

Comment: Pylint seems to ignore settings.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is located in this folder:

C:\Users\dimit\AppData\Roaming\Code\User

if that doesnt work try making c++ file,

make text file and then save it with extention .css, after that open it with visual studio code and go to run, start debugging and choose C++(windows), and it should open you the file, I am not sure but I think this works because I dont have c++ compiler installed so it might not work for you